# Dynamically adding buttons into a table or grid like form layout programmatically

Tags: android, button, dynamic, parent-child, android-tablelayout

I have been on this problem for a while now.
I am hoping to gather top trending keywords and place into an ArrayList. 
Each keyword is to be placed on a toggleButton, (user selects keyword and it enhances search).  I need the buttons to be in a grid like form on the Android mobile app, I also need the buttons to be placed in an ArrayList so I can reference later.  I've tried so many different loops, for loops and loops in loop and keep hitting the same two problems:

prob 1) either the keywords are not read, or repeated in each column if I create the buttons within the layout loop.
prob 2) I create the buttons first and then reference to them in the layout loop and I get a error message:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

I've scanned the internet, I've tried different methods and I think its just something I am missing in my code  (this layer of code is one of many layers, this one holds the buttons...any pointers will be appreciated.

```
        trending = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("one"); add("two"); add("three") ;add("four");add("five");
            add("six");add("seven");add("eight");add("nine");add("ten");
            add("eleven");
        }};

    //LAYOUT SETTINGS 5
    TableLayout rLayout5 = new TableLayout(this);
    rLayout5.setOrientation(TableLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutParams param7 = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    param7.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, rLayout4.getId());
    rLayout5.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEBAA"));

    rLayout5.setLayoutParams(param7);
   // List<ToggleButton> togButtStore = new ArrayList<ToggleButton>();

    int i = 0 ;
    while (i < trending.size()){
        if (i % 3 == 0){
          tr = new TableRow(this);
            rLayout5.addView(tr);
        }
        toggBtn = new ToggleButton(this);
        toggBtn.setText(trending.get(i));
        toggBtn.setId(i);
        toggBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //something here
            }
        });
        tr.addView(toggBtn);
        i++;
    }
    rLayout5.addView(tr);   ///<---error points to this line
    root.addView(rLayout1);
    rLayout1.addView(text1);
    root.addView(rLayout4);
    root.addView(rLayout3);
    root.addView(rLayout5);
    setContentView(root);
}
```

Comment: You are adding tr twice to the rLayout5. Delete the line where you error is....

Comment: oh no haha! I did try it in a for loop also and I was getting the same error message so when just  tried it in the while loop and got exactly the same error message I just went straight to stack fed up. I've been reshuffling  rewriting code all day so missing the simple things.  Thanks it work perfect now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding tr twice to the rLayout5. Delete the line where your error is....